# lfs glibc compilation ld error

Tags: linux, ld, glibc, linux-from-scratch

My host system is Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 00:26:11 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
I want to build a LFS and the glibc compilation stop me now.
Here are the error prompts, thank you.

```
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `getanswer':
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:180: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:483: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `res_gethostbyaddr':
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:644: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:783: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `__GI_res_gethostbyname2':
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:510: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os):/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:636: more undefined references to `__stack_chk_guard' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17/resolv'
make[1]: *** [resolv/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.17'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to solve this problem:

Fixed by this sed in the gcc source before the first pass of gcc:

```
sed -i '/k prot/agcc_cv_libc_provides_ssp=yes' gcc/configure
```

and:

```
sed -i 's/if \((code.*))\)/if (\1 \&\& \!DEBUG_INSN_P (insn))/' gcc/sched-deps.c
```

But these are already mentioned in the LFS-manual. I don't know why I didn't see them when 
I started with LFS :D

Comment: Thanks! Found your post just before I was about to restart with binutils.

Answer (score 1):

Your gcc has stack protection enabled.

To get past this error:

CFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector -O2" ./configure --prefix=/somepath

on my system I ran:

mkdir build

cd build

CFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector -O2" ../configure --prefix=/usr/test_glibc